# How to not create a game object again, if it exist already, while loading a scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

While testing scenes in my application, I did realize that every time that I go back to the main scene (the one with the menu), I get a persistent object created again.

This persistent object is the one that I use to attach on it the game manager script, so there should be always just one, at any time. The problem is that if I go back to the main menu; after loading a scene, it gets created again, so I end up with 2 game objects that are identical.

Is there a way to avoid this; telling Unity that if a gameobject exist already, do not create it again?

I could work around the issue, creating a "boot" scene, which launch once and never gets loaded again (so the boot scene call the main menu); but it feel weird, so I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: How about [this](http://kleber-swf.com/singleton-monobehaviour-unity-projects)?

Comment: I use singletons for the game manager, but the game object is not a singleton itself; I have no control on a game object, to make it a singleton, from what I understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static ClassType instance = null;
void Awake(){
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        return;
    }
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

The awake is called only once in the lifetime of an object. So the first created will get its awake called and it will register itself as the instance. Static remains over scene loading and so does your object since it is marked as DontDestroyOnLoad.

When you come back to the scene that created that object, Unity will add a new instance on top of the existing. The awake of that object will be run and since the instance variable is not null, it will jump and destroy this new instance. The old one does not call Awake anymore so it won't be affected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in the awake I do destroy the object if it already exist as instance? I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html). So you can simply drag/drop your gameobject first scene it wont destroy. So dont need to add same gameobject every scene.

Also if you want to use Singleton pattern you can use [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do use that, so the gameobject persist when I go from the main menu screen to the game screen. The issue is when you are done playing or you want to go back to the main menu (something pretty standard I believe); which result in the first gameobject not being destroyed when the main menu scene load again, while the scene create the same gameobject again.

Comment: If you dont want destroy it. Add one more splash screen and add this gameobject with DontDestroyOnLoad. So you dont comeback same splash scene again.

Comment: note that in unity the Preload scene has to be *before* the splash scene.  the splash is a Unity Scene itself.  Usually it's like Preload Scene -> Networking Scene -> Splash Scene -> often a Login Related Scene -> Main Menu Scene.

Comment: Yep, that's why I was avoiding to use yet another scene to preload the singletons. It is already hard to sync up all that happens (unless you put all your code in update(); which I believe nobody but beginners do). The way that Fafase mentioned works well and it required me to just change 2 lines of code inside my class